# Blocks on frontend disappeared suddenly

Tags: magento2, blocks, frontend, cms

all was good earlier but suddenly all the blocks from front end disappeared, blocks are active in backend but not visible on front end.

https://www.i-ranu.com

Comment: There could be few cases: either there may have been some modifications on your code where those static blocks are called, or try clearing the cache or redeploying once again, it's worth trying.

Comment: Please flush cache and check once

Comment: What does your log say?